# Connecting two cameras into a PI

Tags: gpio, camera, i2c

Is it possible? One connects to the CSI port and the other one to the GPIO ports and use the i2c interface to extract the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly possible.

Only the official Raspberry Pi camera (or clones) can use the CSI port.

Do you have an I2C camera in mind?  A camera connecting via SPI could be faster.

Why not connect a camera via USB?  That's how a lot of webcams work.

Comment: hmmm, never really thought of using a USB but I think it would be harder to attach a USB into a Camera Sensor than to write a program to receive from i2c (I am a better programmer than engineer). I don't want to use webcams for it. I want something to have on board and the video I will be sending will be in low quality VGA.. Thank you for the response; I was super confused about wasting money on something that wouldn't be possible to connect but now i know :)

Comment: Are you saying the camera sensor already talks I2C?  I think the Pi's I2C is limited to 400Kbps.  The Pi's UART can be driven faster than 1Mbps,  The Pi's SPI can be driven at 10s of Mbps.

Comment: I will check it and report it; its going to take some time and I will write a wiki or something :D

Comment: @joan as I understand it from reading [various](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=374258#p374258) [posts](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=377898#p377898) on the camera board, the Pi's camera module is controlled via I2C but image data goes over the MIPI CSI interface.

Comment: Its control interface may well be I2C via SDA/SCL on gpios 28/29.  Those gpios are only available to the user via the P5 interface on the Rev.2 boards.  I don't know if it was possible to control the camera by sending commands on those pins.

Comment: Why don't you want to use webcamera? It is easiest way to connect second camera to RPI.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi's compute module with the I/O driver board is capable of driving two Pi camera modules and in the last few days the firmware has been enhanced to provide [stereoscopic capabilities](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=85012) too. As that post makes clear though, this is for the compute module only, it'll never work on the Pi as only one CSI interface is exposed on the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the multi camera adapter for Raspberry Pi to use two cameras.

Comment: Could you provide a link? Are you referring to this device: [Multi Camera Adapter Module for Raspberry Pi](http://www.arducam.com/multi-camera-adapter-module-raspberry-pi/)?